# 6070 Error when adding invoice to QbOnline via .net sdk v3

Tags: c#

I am trying to add an Invoice with above specified XMl but getting 6070 Error Code.Amount is not equal to Qty * UnitPrice.Is there a way to ignore this error. 
Here is my Add invoice request in Xml format.

```
<Invoice  xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3"> 
  <DocNumber>    aa444</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2013-08-06</TxnDate>
  <Line>
    <Amount>20.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef name="HomecareServices">5</ItemRef>
      <UnitPrice>20</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
      <ServiceDate>2013-08-01</ServiceDate>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <CustomerRef name="ABCD">10</CustomerRef>
  <BillAddr>
    <Line1>ABCD- 10</Line1>
  </BillAddr>
  <DueDate>2013-08-10</DueDate>
  <TotalAmt>20.00</TotalAmt>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be because qty = 2, unit price = 20 so amount should be 40?

Comment: you are correct Peter but for fixed job we r not considering Amount=Qty * Unit Price.

Answer (score -1):

SalesItemLineDetail is wrong, should be InvoiceItemLineDetail